# ImportError: cannot import name porter python

Tags: python, installation, nlp, nltk, porter-stemmer

I am importing nltk library in my project and it is giving following error. If someone has same error, please help.

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nitai/Dropbox/thesis/PycharmProjects/auto_tagger2/tagger.py", line 4, in <module>
    import buildVocab
  File "/home/nitai/Dropbox/thesis/PycharmProjects/auto_tagger2/buildVocab.py", line 4, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 25, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import porter
ImportError: cannot import name porter
```

I have installed all nltk packages. I don't know.

Comment: Does that happen just by import? When you run "import nltk" in the console it happens?

Comment: How did you install nltk? Did you use pip install? May be worth checking whether you installed this against the same version of Python that you're running

Comment: `Porter` is a name of a stemmer, to reduce words to their stems. It could be that it needs to be installed separately.

Answer (score 5):

If you have downloaded all data packages from NLTK, i.e.

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('all')
```

Porter Stemmer in NLTK is a class not a package/module.

You should import PorterStemmer class instead:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> porter.stem('went')
u'went'
>>> porter.stem('running')
u'run'
```

Also, check that you have the latest stable version of NLTK by installing with `pip`. Otherwise, you might be using an unstable/outdated version of NLTK. See http://www.nltk.org/install.html

Comment: Judging from the traceback, the OP didn't actually intend to import the name "porter" at all – they might not even want to do any stemming. The last line in the OP's scripts seems to be triggered by `import nltk`.